# Get facebook posts by hashtags

Tags: facebook, curl, hashtag

I've been spending 2 days on Google, looking for a way to retrieve Facebook posts by hashtag.
I already know that the API doesn't allow anything with hashtags and I find it stupid, but that's it.

Now what I want to try is to get those posts through curl, but I'm not that good at it.
Let's say for example that you want all public posts containing #baseball.
When you're logged in, you can see them there: `https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/baseball`
So basically, I want to curl that URL to get the posts. But of course it doesn't work...
Here is the script I use:

```php
        $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/baseball';
        $http = curl_init($url);
        $fake_user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3';
        curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $fake_user_agent);
        $result = curl_exec($http);
```

As you can imagine, `$result` is empty...
I've tried to get an access token before doing that, but even though I add it to the URL, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you try authenticating first?

Comment: I used the Facebook class to do it before using curl to grab the page, but it did not change anything (I'm using the Facebook SDK for PHP). I'm able to get an access token, so I guess I'm logged in the right way...

Comment: I don't know the FB api. But usually you'd have to add this access token in some way to subsequent calls, correct?

Comment: Yes, when you use the graph api... But in what I'm trying to do, the grpah api doesn't work, so I can't use graph.facebook.com. That's why I really need to curl www.facebook.com.

Comment: Well this is what I meant. as a test, open an incognito tab in Chrome. Visit that link of yours (fb.com/hashtag/baseball) - it says "You must log in to see this page." I guess this is what your Curl also gets. So try providing this access token (I guess via headers or something) in plain curl call? Or I don't understand the whole thing :)

Comment: No, it doesn't work either... I just give up that, I'll wait for an update of the Facebook API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=YOURHASHTAGWITHNO#&type=post&limit=999&access_token=YOURMEGATOKENHERE

Use Facebook SDK + Facebook APP creator with API ID and secret to generate token.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.
And please don't shout ...

Comment: This is not a link answer, it is literally the url the OP has to request via curl. Also, this method does now not work any longer due to an update by Facebook in mid-2014